# Powershell - Foreach, IF, Test-Path & Drive Variable

Tags: powershell

Hello Stackoverflow users,

I am noob at scripting and powershell.

I have the following script that gets all the drive letters on the host into a text file. I need to get the correct drive letter into a variable by performing a test-path. However it is not working. I know I am close but cannot get it to work.
Does anyone know how to fix the script?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" | Select DeviceID | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders > c:\DeviceID.txt -Force
$DeviceID = Get-Content C:\DeviceID.txt
$DeviceID | ForEach {$_.TrimEnd()} | ? {$_.trim() -ne '' } > c:\DeviceID.txt

$DeviceID = Get-Content C:\DeviceID.txt
$Path = "$_\Apps\NetprobeNT\"
$PathExists = Test-Path $Path

foreach ($DeviceID in $DeviceID)
{
If ($PathExists -eq $True)
{
$DeviceDrive = $DeviceID}
Else 
{
$DeviceDrive = "C:"}
}
```

I think the following line is the problem

```
$Path = "$_\Apps\NetprobeNT\"
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

This relates to  [PowerShell - drive variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070582/powershell-drive-variable) for more information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `$_` variable is not defined anywhere. It represents the current object only within `{script block}` of `ForEach-Object`, `Where-Object` etc. cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out yourself, this line is problematic:

```
$Path = "$_\Apps\NetprobeNT"
```

`$_` is not defined in this scope, and so the resulting string just becomes `"\Apps\NetprobeNT"`

I would use `Join-Path` inside `Where-Object` (where `$_` will refer to the current item in the pipeline):

To find the drives on which the folder exists, you can use `Where-Object`:

```
$CorrectDrive = $DeviceIDs |Where-Object {
    Test-Path $(Join-Path $_ "Apps\NetprobeNT") 
}
if(-not $CorrectDrive)
{
    $CorrectDrive = "C:"
}
```

---

That being said, your method for getting the DeviceID's is pretty convoluted - simply use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to grab the DeviceID value(s) and nothing else:

```
$DeviceIDs = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID
```

Comment: hi Mathias, with some help it was resolved with the following - $DeviceDrive = "C:"
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" |
Where-Object { Test-Path "$($_.DeviceID)\Apps\NetprobeNT\" } |
Foreach-Object {
    $DeviceDrive = $_.DeviceID
}